# The "camera" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been going through tags today, and I came across the [camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) tag. Is this tag really valuable? It seems rather redundant, and I think it runs the high risk of becoming overused and rather useless. Just about every question on this site so far could be tagged with [camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera), as the vast bulk of our questions are camera related, with the minority falling into the post-processing and printing categories.

Answer (score 5):

Seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I'm for killing it. In some cases, [body](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body) might be appropriate, and [camera-recommendation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera-recommendation) often is.

**I went through and removed the tag from all existing questions. Now it is dead.**

Comment: Lazy New Year's Day? Good stuff :-) It doesn't seem to be quite dead yet though - see e.g. the [camera] [Top Users page](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/camera/topusers). That may be some of SE's aggressive caching waiting to rebuild though.

Comment: That page has gone now, so I'm guessing it was just caching.

Answer (score 1):

Bump :-)

I just found this tag today and came to pretty much the same conclusion: it's not going to add any value as *de facto* all our questions relate to a camera in one way or another. I'd suggest we delete the tag, but is there anything we can do to stop it coming back again?